Formal Smoothness as a Local Property
I have a question about one proof step in Proposition 1.3.5 in Olsson's Algebraic Spaces and Stacks.
Proposition. A morphism of schemes $f:X \to Y$ is smooth if and only if it is locally of finite presentation and the following property holds: For every commutative diagram of schemes
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y_0' @>y_0>> X \\ @ViVV @VVfV \\ Y' @>>a> Y
\end{CD}$$
where $i$ is a closed embedding defined by a square-zero ideal, there exists an open covering $Y' = \bigcup_i U_i'$ and morphisms $\rho_i : U_i' \to X$ over $Y$ such that the restriction of $\rho_i$ to $U_{i,0}' = U_i' \times_{Y'} Y_0'$ is equal to the restriction of $y_0$.
For the 'if' direction fix those objects from the statement and consider affine $Y'$. The goal is to modify $\rho_i$ so that they glue. We denote by
$$ \varepsilon_{ij} = \rho_i|_{U_{ij}} - \rho_j|_{U_{ij}} \in \operatorname{Hom}_{U_{ij}}(y_0^* \Omega_{X/Y}^1, \mathcal{J})$$ the unique element such that the simply transitive torsor action (Olsson, 1.3.3) of these lifts sends $\rho_j|_{U_{ij}}$ to $\rho_i|_{U_{ij}}$. Olsson then shows via a Čech cohomology argument that there exist $\lambda_i \in \mathscr{H}\operatorname{om}(y_0^* \Omega_{X/Y}^1, \mathcal{J})$ with
$$ \varepsilon_{ij} = \lambda_i|_{U_{ij}} - \lambda_j|_{U_{ij}} \in \operatorname{Hom}_{U_{ij}}(y_0^* \Omega_{X/Y}^1, \mathcal{J}).$$ He then claims that $\rho_i' = \lambda_i * \rho_i$ agree on the overlaps $U_{ij}$.
Question. Why do the $\rho_i'$ agree on the overlaps?
I probably misunderstood some of the definitions floating around. Simply trying to compute $\rho_i'|_{U_{ij}} - \rho_j'|_{U_{ij}}$ with the given relations with $\varepsilon$ leads nowhere for me.
